# Using VBA for a MS Access 2000 Textbox's Control Source

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm in the process of converting a MS Access 2000 database to MySQL, while still using Access for the front end.

I've come across a problem where some forms get the data from fields in MS Access tables. IE, the "Control Source" value is set to a specific field, and when the form is run, its creates the required number of Textboxes to match the number of entries in the table and populates them with the data from the tables.

Now I'd like to be able to set the Control Source of the Textbox to call a VBA function, which get's the data from MySQL, and populates the textbox with the entries in MySQL table.  I'm not sure how this is achieved, or if its even possible.

So could I just create a VBA function and set it in the Control Source property for the Textbox, or do I need a more complicated solution ?

Comment: The ControlSource would just be `=MyFunction()`, though if you were passing values, you'd have to include those, which can be tricky knowing how to specify them exactly. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any code for the text boxes to display. Simply use a linked table to MySql, and the form should function as before. There is little if any reason I can think of here to dump the use of bound forms and bound controls.

Comment: That is one option, though my problem is that I'm using temporary tables, and as far as I know I can't create link to one them in order to do that. Unless you know a way ?

Comment: Why create links? You can use dynamic SQL to connect to them in the Recordsource of your form.